# How to wait for the user to be logged in, in Velocity integration tests

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

In order to perform my integration tests, the callback from the `Meteor.loginWithPassword(...` has to have been executed.

If I postpone the test until the user exists, or some `Session` variable is defined, the tests are ignored.

This is my login function:

```
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, forge.util.encode64(aesKey), function(error) {
     if(!error) {
        Log.info("user loged in");
        Session.set("loggedIn", true);
     ...         
  })
```

and then in the Mocha test:

```
  Meteor.startup(function () {
     Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
        if (Session.get("loggedIn")) {
           c.stop();
           MochaWeb.testOnly(function () {
              Log.info("executing tests");
              describe("the KeyPair has been created", function () {
              ...
```

My question is: is there a way to make mocha wait for some state or do I have to mock the environment (which would defeat the integration test purpose)?

Also, on code changes, I get following error:

```
stream error Network error: ws://localhost:51366/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

thank you for your support

Comment: I think you would be interested in this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3572

Comment: this would definitely be useful but it would not solve my issue: if I set the autorun to wait for the user to be logged in it is still triggered before the callback

Comment: I'm saying the proposed feature would help with your problem - if there was an `onLogin` callback on the client, you wouldn't have to do all this stuff. You should comment and indicate your support for the new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature request that @stubailo pointed out has now been implemented. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3572 for more details.